# PowerShell - Connect-ExchangeOnline Error - Cannot load file or Assembly

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

Installed ExchangeOnlineManagement module on two servers, verified the directories post install, however whenever I try to execute the basic command:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline
```

Or any versions of it such as:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName ####@###.com -ShowBanner:$false
```

I am met with the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The 
system cannot find the file specified.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ExchangeOnlineManagement\3.0.0\netFramework\ExchangeOnlineManagement.psm1:726 char:21
+                     throw $_.Exception.InnerException
```

I have verified that .NET 4.6 is installed. Not really sure what to check here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Installation of .NET 4.8 resolved the same issue for me on Server 2016.